# What Expression Behind Python For In Loop Does

Tags: python

In this example:

```
sorted_data = [files.data[ind] for ind in sort_inds]
```

May someone please provide an explanation as to how the expression behind the for loop is related or how it is working, thanks.

Comment: Read on list compression

Comment: I think @karthikr means list comprehension http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Please don't downvote a question just because you already know the answer. I spent quite a while googling for this, merely because I didn't know the name for it. Seeing the expression *precede* the for-in definitely made me scratch my head, having never seen a list comprehension expressed this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

In other words

```
sorted_data = [files.data[ind] for ind in sort_inds]
```

is equivalent to:

```
sorted_data = []
for ind in sort_inds:
    sorted_data.append(files.data[ind])
```

It's just a lot more readable using the comprehension

Answer (score 2):

ok so here is a simple example:

say i have a list of ints:

```
nums = [1,2,3]
```

and i do this:

```
[i**2 for i in nums]
```

it will output:

```
[1, 4, 9]
```

this is equivalent to this:
    for i in nums:
        list.append(i**2)

because it iterated through the list and squared each item in the list

another example:

say  i have a list of strings like this:

```
list1 = ['hey, jim','hey, pam', 'hey dwight']
```

and I do this:

```
[phrase.split(',') for phrase in list1]
```

this will output this list:

```
[['hey', ' jim'], ['hey', ' pam'], ['hey dwight']]
```

this is equivalent too:

```
for phrase in list1:
    new_phrase = phrase.split(',')
    list.append(new_phrase)
```

it went through and made a list out of each item but it used  split on each item

its basically a compacted for loop and instead of using `append()` it just creates the list!. it is much more readable and takes less lines

learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438701/what-expression-behind-python-for-in-loop-does)

Answer (score 0):

It means for every item in this case ind present in sort_inds, pass it as a parameter to the function files.data[ind].

Save the result in a list (sorted_data)